# Adding members to Google Cloud SQL project

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am not able to add new members to Google Cloud SQL project. We have to do this in order to get useraccess on web app created with Google apps script. Invitation is sent, but, when user tries to approve, the following message appears:

```
Server Error
Whoops! Our bad.
Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send 
feedback" link below. Copy the tracking number below, and include it with your 
feedback. Thanks!
Tracking Number: undefined
Send feedback
```

Any ideas why this is happening? This used to work previously.

Thanks, Lars